# why does AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes return a routevaluedictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Related to MVC 5.2

Whilst refactoring some code I came across the HtmlHelper method[1]:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes (object htmlAttributes);
```

I wondered why it returned a `RouteValueDictionary` rather than a simpler `IDictionary<string, object>` which is generally used for Html Attributes.

I've assumed that this is unintentional, but wondered if I was actually missing something more profound?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and have noticed in the latest ASP.NET core 7.0 documentation this method returns `IDictionary`:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes (object htmlAttributes);
```

My conclusion was also that using `RouteValueDictionary` was unintentional.

[Microsoft Learn - HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes?view=aspnetcore-7.0)